# How did twitter implement new autocomplete feature in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

Twitter has an awesome new way to enter "@" and "#" in the latest iPhone app.

http://blog.twitter.com/2011/03/twitter-for-iphone-ipad-even-better.html

When you type "#" or "@" and then type characters it instantly starts to autocomplete in a table below. How are they doing this? It feels native, but is it?

If it's native, how did they do it? UITextView with an active UITableView? It's really fast and smooth, so I'm guessing they load the phone with trending #'s and your @'s and it's fast because the data is local (it goes to just typing if it's not there).

But I'm wondering if there was a way to achieve this affect with data that is remote on a webserver using async calls.

Any thoughts on how to do this / get started?

Answer (score 1):

If by 'native' you mean, build into the SDK, then I have to disappoint you, this is not a build-in SDK feature (there is something similar with the UISearchController/UISearchBar classes, but that's not what Twitter is leveraging).

This however, does not mean that you cannot build it yourself. I believe it would be quite simple. All you would have to do is monitor every time the user inputs text into the UITextView (this can easily be done using the UITextView delegate methods). You do a check on all the text, and if the user enters an '@' or a '#', or any other symbol you want to watch for, you create/show a UITableView beneath the text view (or wherever you want it).

As for the table view's datasource, it would have to be based on information you gather through search. When Twitter shows you a list of trending tags, etc. I would think it is something they have pulled down when you synced your feed, and then cached somewhere. If you were using a web server, you could do the same. When the user starts entering specific text, you could do a search on the server. If you do the network requests asynchronously, you can display a UIActivityIndicator in the table view, until you've gotten a response from the server. If the user enters more text before the server has 'replied' to you, simply cancel the old server request, and start a new one.

I haven't implemented something like this myself, and I have no knowledge of how it would perform in real-life, but if I was to implement something similar off the top of my head, this would be the aproach I would pursue. It might not suit your case perfectly, but hopefully, it will have given you some inspiration :)

Comment: Thanks! This seems like a function that would be great to have a three20 style library around. Autocomplete into a uitableview asynchronously from a webserver would be very handy. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: I'm eating my own uninformed words. Looks like three20 actually does do something like this.. http://joehewitt.com/post/the-three20-project/

Comment: Interesting you found it in Three20, seems like that solves the UI part of your problem :)